# Perform multiplication in zk grid

Tags: user-interface, zk

How I can perform multiplication in zk grid my grid is look like this

Rate   Qty  Amount

|2    ----- 3 ---6
|
|4------4----16|

Comment: show me zul code and I can help. You have several solutions, depending of MVC, MVVM or just how you implement the grid (renderer, template,...)

Comment: kindly refer me the solutions if i will have any issues i will tell you

Answer (score 1):

The `each` stands for the var name how you did name the variable in the for each.  By default this is `each`.
If MVVM :

you could add to your VM :

```
public long countNumbers (int first, int second) {
    return (long)first + second;
}
```

in zul :

```
<label value="@load(vm.countNumbers(each.number1, each.numer2))"/>
```

In MVVM or MVC :

If its needed regulary, you could write your own taglib with this method.(works also for MVC)
You need to create a tld file in the WEB-INF/tld folder. :

```
<taglib>
    <!-- count numbers to each other -->
    <function>
        <name>countUp</name>
        <function-class>your.path.Classname</function-class>
        <function-signature>
            java.lang.Long countNumbers(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
        </function-signature>
        <description>counts the 2 numbers to each other.</description>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Then you create a new java util class (watch out, the method need to be static):

```
public static Long countNumbers (Integer first, Integer second) {
    return (Long)first + second;
}
```

And in zul :

```
<?taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/taglibname.tld" prefix="ct"?>

<label  value="@load(ct:countUp(each.number1,each.number2))"/>
```

If you use a renderer, you set all the objects of a row directly in java so counting up 2 values there should not be a problem, cause you will have the original object already.

Edit : change the return type to long (2 big int can cause overflow)